# Valgrind не находит утечку объектов, хранящихся в QList

Tags: c++, linux, valgrind

При рефакторинге своего кода привнёс в проект утечку памяти. Пытался найти её с помощью Valgrind, однако он её не показал. Выглядит утечка так:

1. Я разбираю входные данные и заношу указатели на найденные объекты в *QList*:
   *listOfData.append(new MyData(sourcePiece));*
2. Я обрабатываю эти объекты через *QtConcurrent*, копируя из них нужную информацию.
3. Я выхожу из области видимости *listOfData*, и объекты из списка теряются.

Появилась утечка из-за того, что я попытался вместо списка указателей сделать список объектов. Сделал, но потом заставить QtConcurrent нормально работать с этим списком не получилось, и я вернулся к списку указателей - а вернуть строчку *while (!listOfData.empty()) delete listOfData.takeFirst();* забыл. Но это так, отступление, а главный вопрос в том, почему *Valgrind* не заметил *new* без соответствующего *delete*? Это нормальное поведение, или стоит написать в баг-трекер?

**Update:**  Причина найдена (спасибо @Swift): под Linux библиотеки Qt поставляются (по умолчанию) только в release-версии, поэтому Valgrind не видит место, где теряется последний указатель на хранящиеся в списке объекты (внутри деструктора QList).

**Update2:** Переоткрываем проблему. Я проверил предположение с помощью такого кода:

```
#include <list>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <QList>

using namespace std;

int main(int , char *[])
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    for (int i=0;i<10;++i)
    {
        QList<int*> l;
        for (int j=0;j<10;++j)
            l.push_back(new int(rand()));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

При проверке такого кода *Valgrind* правильно находит утечку, как при использовании *QList*, так и с *std::list*. Следовательно, проблема где-то у меня в коде. Но выкладывать большие куски кода сюда нельзя, поэтому придётся искать самому. Пока что единственным вариантом остаётся предположение @KoVadim о том, что где-то ссылки на используемую память остаются, поэтому она не видна как потерянная. Но в этом я сомневаюсь.

Comment: попробуйте сделать маленький пример, который воспроизводит данную ситуацию. Возможно, утечки и нет (то есть, ссылка на объект осталась ещё где то и все ок).

Comment: @KoVadim, утечка там точно была. Я побегал по коммитам в git, нашёл версию без утечек, потом нашёл первый коммит с утечкой (утекает примерно 60-70Мб в час), и по внесённым правкам утечку обнаружил. Этот-то кусок я на умные указатели переведу, я и занялся рефакторингом, чтобы по возможности избавиться от управляемой вручную памяти, но хочу наработать способ гарантированного обнаружения утечек через Valgrind. На будущее.

Comment: многие думаю, что если память увеличивается, то это утечка. Если к примеру, будем добавлять в список объекты, но не удалять их, то это как бы не утечка. В с++ утечка - это если есть объекты в памяти, на которые нет ссылок/указателей. Если хотя бы одна есть, то это не утечка.

Comment: @KoVadim, Вы исходную запись прочитали? Объекты создаются через new и заносятся в список, дополнительные ссылки/указатели на них не создаются, потом список уничтожается, и единственные (хранящиеся в списке) указатели теряются. То, что Вы написали, совершенно правильно, но к ситуации не относится.

Comment: да, я читал. Более того, я много искал утечек с помощью valgrind и qt. Он все находит. Другое дело, что у valgdind'a есть "гарантированная утечка", а есть "возможная утечка". И о последнем обычно забывают.

Comment: а код случайно не многопоточный?

Comment: Частично многопоточный. То есть многопоточные и однопоточные участки хорошо разделены. Список объектов строится однопоточно, потом по всему списку проходимся QtConcurrent::blockingMappedReduced, дальше опять однопоточно работаем. А может мешать Valgrind'у то, что программа не завершается самостоятельно, а крутится, пока её не убьёшь?

Answer (score 2):

В коде вида

```
{
    QList<MyObject*> list;
    list.append(new MyObject());
} // leak
```

Утечка происходит в приватной реализации, если Qt не собран в отладочном режиме, то Valgrind точно ничего не заметит, заметит ли в обратном случае - бабушка надвое сказала. Надо явно вызывать

```
qDeleteAll(list);
```

Чтобы избегать утечки. Альтернативой является использование  умных указателей QSharedPointer.

Comment: *"если Qt не собран с Valgrind"* -- это ещё зачем?

Comment: Да, вопрос вызывает фраза "если Qt не собран с Valgrind". Разве отладочных библиотек Qt не должно быть достаточно?

Comment: Но за наводку на qDeleteAll спасибо. Это явно красивее и понятнее, чем мой вариант с while... delete(list.takeFirst()).

Comment: @BMP Если они есть и зависит от платформы. На линукс то по-умолчанию только  релиз версия и  QTCreator может запускает  Valgrins с  опциями, подавляющими ошибки вызванными действиями в библиотеке. В чистом виде  Valgrind ругается на Qt что только держись. Почему-то возникали случаи что библиотеку надо пере собирать после установки анализатора, возможно , зависимости

Comment: @Swift, я посмотрел в папке с установленным Qt, и библиотек .so.d действительно не нашёл. Я правильно понимаю, что их можно получить, только скачивая не инсталлятор (.run), а исходники, и собирая и debug, и release-версии библиотек? Или инсталлятор можно запустить с каким-нибудь ключом, чтобы ставились обе версии?